# Изменение значения $_POST по нажатии кнопки

Tags: php

Переменная получает значение из $_POST (в ней содержится выбранный номер дня):

```
$wday = $_POST["warmday"];
```

Эта переменная используется для создания таблицы данных этого дня. Мне нужно создать 2 кнопки, которые уменьшают/увеличивают на 1 значение $_POST и обновляют страницу с изменённым числом, чтобы страница отображала данные за прошлый/следующий день.

Comment: В чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как добиться желаемого результата, и поэтому я сделал данный пост в надежде на помощь.

Comment: ну одной кнопкой передаете действие увеличения, другой - уменьшение.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу и важно изменять именно POST данные, то делаете форму на странице и размещаете внутри 2 кнопки submit с разным value, большим и маленьким. В зависимости от того на какую кнопку нажмут, вы получите в переменную требуемое значение.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="warmday" value="<?= ($_POST['warmday'] - 1) ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="warmday" value="<?= ($_POST['warmday'] + 1) ?>">
</form>
<?php
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);
?>
```